# Date in log file using ofstream

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

Below is the code I have to write every time I want to include the date in my log file at the moment. I'm looking for a way to not have to write my `CurrentDateToString()` everytime I want to write something in my file.

```
ofstream log;
log.open("test.log", ios_base::app);
log << CurrentDateToString() << " | " << "first line" << endl;
log << CurrentDateToString() << " | " << "second line" << endl;
log.close();
```

And here is my `CurrentDateToString()` function:

```
// convert date to formatted string
string CurrentDateToString()
{  
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm* timeInfo;
    char buffer[80];

    time(&rawtime);
    timeInfo = localtime(&rawtime);

    strftime(buffer, 80, "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S", timeInfo);
    string dateString(buffer);

    return dateString;
}
```

The goal here is to be able to write those lines instead of the current lines I'm writing:

```
log << "first line" << endl;
log << "second line" << endl;
```

Do I have to write a log class and overload operator<< or is there another way to do it ?

Comment: Use a dedicated logging library, like log4cpp or so.

Comment: If you override `<<`, won't you you get the date for *every* use of `<<`?

Comment: I believe the idea was to create a type `class Logger` and override the operator for that class only. There is no reason to return an ostream from that, so that further inserter invocations don't get the date.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I will look into it but I don't know if a specific library is really necessary. Is it ? 
@ScottHunter I don't want to have the date for my other uses of `<<` but just for the things I will put in my log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to implement a stream which automagically adds (or removes) characters, e.g., adding a date, is to create a filtering stream buffer. You'd derive a class from `std::streambuf` which massages the characters it receives into the necessary form and then forwards them to an underlying stream buffer.

For your use of adding a date at the start of the line you'd simply observe newline characters being received and set a flag `need_date` if there is a newline. When a character is being written while `need_date` is set, the date is written and the flag is cleared.

Here is how that could look for your date:

```
#include <streambuf>
class logbuf
    : public std::streambuf {
    std::streambuf* sbuf;
    bool            need_date{true};
    using traits_type = std::char_traits<char>;

    int overflow(int c) override {
        if (c != traits_type::eof()) {
            if (need_date) {
                std::string date{CurrentDateToString()};
                this->sbuf->sputn(date.c_str(), date.size());
                need_date = false;
            }
            if (c == '\n') {
                need_date = true;
            }
            return this->sbuf->sputc(c);
        }
        else {
            return traits_type::not_eof(c);
        }
    }
    int sync() override { return this->sbuf->pubsync(); }
public:
    logbuf(std::streambuf* sbuf): sbuf(sbuf) {}
};
```

The `virtual` function `overflow()` is called every time there is no space in the stream buffer's buffer. Since there is no output buffer set up that happens for each character (performance can be improved by adding an override for `xsputn()` and/or adding buffering). The function `sync()` is called every time the stream is flushed. Since nothing is buffered, the flush request is simply forwarded to the underlying stream buffer.

Below is a simple demo using this stream buffer. The creation of a suitable underlying stream buffer, e.g., a `std::filebuf`, and an `std::ostream` can be packaged into a class derived from `std::ostream`.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    logbuf sbuf(std::cout.rdbuf());
    std::ostream logout(&sbuf);
    logout << "hello\nwordl\n";
    logout << "\n";
    logout << "goodbye\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for the delay, I didn't look at my code this weekend. Your code works perfectly for `ostream` but I don't know how to make it works for an `ofstream`. I don't know how to link `sbuf` to my `ofstream`. If I try to just change `ostream` by `ofstream`, I get an error telling me that there are `no matching function for call`. Any tips ?

Comment: @Aleph0: you _could_ use `file.std::ostream.rdbuf(&sbuf)` to install a stream buffer into a `std::ofstream`. However, I recommend **not** to do so! Instead you should change interfaces taking an `std::ofstream&` to rather take a `std::ostream&`! There hardly ever a need to use `std::ofstream` specific methods other than in the context where these objects are created.